# using a switch statement in a setter

Tags: java, setter

This is probably a really silly question, but I figured I'd try asking! Basically the question is this: can I use a switch statement in my setters?

Here's what I'm doing: I've created a Monster class with the attributes of healthPoints, description, damage, and type, in which type is an enum. In my driver, I've written a few lines of code that will randomly generate a monster type from the enum values, and it will create a new monster using that type.

The issue is that when I display the monster stats, it shows healthPoints and damage as 0, and description as null. When I try to run the program using the default Monster constructor, it crashes and shows a NullPointerException error.

I think the error is in either my setters or the constructors. Each of the setters has a switch case inside, which sets a certain number of healthPoints, damage, and a specific description depending on the type of monster that is randomly generated. I'm not sure if it's even okay to use a switch statement in a setter because I've never really had to before.

Here is some of my code. First, my constructors.

```
public Monster(int healthPoints, monsterType type, int damage, String description)
{
    setHealthPoints(healthPoints);
    setType(type);
    setDamage(damage);
    setDescription(description);
}

public Monster(monsterType type)
{
    setType(type);
}
```

Below is one of the setters.

```
public void setHealthPoints(int healthPoints)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case DROW: 
            healthPoints = 30;
            break;
        case LICH:
            healthPoints = 40;
            break;
        case ORC:
            healthPoints = 20;
            break;
        case OWLBEAR:
            healthPoints = 20;
            break;
        case RUST_MONSTER:
            healthPoints = 10;
            break;
    }
    this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
}
```

And below is the line in the driver that creates the monster.

```
int number = new Random().nextInt(monsterType.values().length);
        Monster monster = new Monster(monsterType.values ()[number]);
```

I want the monster's healthPoints, damage, and description to be set depending on the type of monster that is generated. I'm not sure if this can be done using switches in the setters, and I feel like my mistake is probably obvious and I'm just not seeing it because I've been staring at it for a long time...or, if there's a different or easier way to do this, please let me know! Thank you for taking the time to read; I tried to make my question/problems thorough.

Comment: I think you should make your structure more easy and readable. Use a `Monster` as **interface** and then create explicit subclasses like `Drow`, `Lich`, `Orc`, `Owlbear` and `RustMonster` that all implement `Monster`. You can also make your `Monster` an **abstract class** if you have code that would be equal among all those monsters. This code then goes to `Monster` whereas the rest goes to the subclasses. Then identify common structures, the monsters should only contain what makes them unique to the others. Like a variable **maximalHealth** or so. The setter itself will be the same for all.

Comment: One of your issues seems to be that your first constructor should call `setType()` before calling setHealthPoints(). The latter method depends on the (apparent) instance variable, `type`.

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**. Classes should start with an **upper-case** character. So your `enum` should be `MonsterType` instead.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

Yes you can use `switch` cases in the constructor and in methods. The issue is that you are calling `setHealthPoints` before `setType` but the first methods uses the `type` in its `switch` statement:

```
setHealthPoints(healthPoints);
setType(type);
```

Therefore the variable `type` is **uninitialized** when you visit the `switch` of `setHealthPoints` and thus currently `null`.

A `switch` statement will throw a `NullPointerException` if its argument is `null`. Thus you get the **NPE**.

You can fix this by first executing `setType`.

---

### Advice on game architecture

You should create a more readable structure that is also easier to maintain and especially easy to extend.

Therefore consider creating a `Monster` **interface** or **abstract class**. After that create explicit monsters as subclasses. The class `Monster` will contain everything that is equal among all monsters, try to abstract from specific monsters. The monsters themselve will then only contain what differentiates them from the rest.

For example you could use some kind of this:

```
public abstract class Monster {
    private int mHealthPoints;
    private int mDamage;
    private String mDescription;

    public Monster(int healthPoints, int damage, String description) {
        this.mHealthPoints = healthPoints;
        this.mDamage = damage;
        this.mDescription = description;
    }

    public int getHealthPoints() {
        return this.mHealthPoints;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return this.mDamage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.mDescription;
    }
}
```

And then you have specific monster classes like

```
public class Orc extends Monster {
    private static int HEALTH = 20;
    private static int DAMAGE = 10;
    private static String DESCRIPTION = "Nasty orc.";

    public Orc() {
        super(Orc.HEALTH, Orc.DAMAGE, Orc.DESCRIPTION);
    }
}
```

You also don't need that `monsterType` *enum* anymore since you can differentiate via `monster instanceof Orc`. However for a really modular design you shouldn't work on specific classes. Instead use a lot of **interfaces** that describe **properties** and **abilities**.

For example interfaces like:

```
CanAttack
IsAttackable
HasHealth
CanWalk
CanFly
CanCollide
...
```

Your game logic then may be built only on those interfaces. For example `CanAttack` could look like:

```
public interface CanAttack {
    void attack(IsAttackable target);
}
```

The huge advantage is that you then can easily extend your game. For example by creating monsters with arbitrary combinations of abilities:

```
public SuperFlyingPig extends Monster implements
        CanAttack, HasHealth, CanWalk, CanFly {
    ...
}
```

And it magically will work without any additional coding effort since your logic will not care for the specific monster. It will only work on the **interfaces**.

Comment: Thorough answer that explains the issue and how to solve it, plus goes beyond that by showing how to improve on the current code in general. Well done.